# Subscribe to another observable when request failed

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a method which call a service method `myService.createResource()`. When it fails, I set `isResourceCreatingFailed`  to `true`.

```
doSomething(): void {
    this.myService
      .createResource()
      .pipe(
        finalize(() => {
          this.isLoading = false;
        })
      )
      .subscribe(
        () => {
          // ... some event emits 
        },
        (error) => {
          this.isResourceCreatingFailed = true;
        }
      );
  }
```

`createResource` method from `myService` looks like this:

```
  createResource(body) {
    return this.http.post(url, body).pipe(
      switchMap((response) => {
        return this.pollUntilResourceCreated(response.id).pipe(
          timeout(8000),
          catchError((error) => throwError(error))
        );
      })
    );
  }
```

First it makes an HTTP call to create a resource. It can take up to 10 seconds in worst case and if it fails I need to make another call `myService.deleteResourse().subscribe()` but also throw an error in order to set `isResourceCreatingFailed`  in my first code example to `true`. I've added `catchError((error) => throwError(error))` which returns an error but what is the best place to do the `myService.delete()`?

`myService.deleteResourse()` will always be called from `createResourse`, that's why I want to keep it there.

Comment: So you want to make same API call with same request 1 more time?

Comment: hi! no, i want to do `myService .createResource()`, but if it's failing I want to do `deleteResource()`

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that comes to mind to add the "complete" method in `doSomething`:

```
doSomething(): void {
    this.myService
      .createResource()
      .pipe(
        finalize(() => {
          this.isLoading = false;
        })
      )
      .subscribe(
        () => {
          // ... some event emits 
        },
        (error) => {
          this.isResourceCreatingFailed = true;
        }, 
        () => {
          this.anotherService.anotherRequest().subscribe() //and go on
        }
      );
  }
```

**EDIT**:

why don't you want to write the logic for working with another service in a block with an error?

```
(error) => {
   this.isResourceCreatingFailed = true;
   this.anotherService.anotherRequest().subscribe()
}
```

If I misunderstood something, please, explain

Comment: Hi! Sorry, I've updated my question. `anotherService.anotherRequest()` is actually `myService.deleteResourse()`. It will always be called from createResourse, that's why I want to keep it there. Another thing, I don't think it's a good practice to do `.subscribe()` inside of another `.subscribe()`

Comment: If you want to do something after subscribe you have to do it in subscribe, there are no other variants. And It's not a bad practice. You can take out ```myService.deleteResourse()``` in separate method and call him after subscribe for beauty:)